# Designing a heuristic to split full name into relevant fields

Tags: c#, .net

Basically, I need to create a method that will do its darn best to take a name field and split it into title, firstNames and lastNames.

E.g. Mr. Daniel George Trump will become:
Title: Mr.
FirstNames: Daniel George
LastNames: Trump

or

Mr. Daniel George Trump and Mrs. Sarah Trump will become:
Title: Mr and Mrs
FirstNames: Daniel George & Sarah
LastNames: Trump & Trump (some inputs may be two people with different surnames).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might make a list of standard titles (Mr., Mrs., etc.) and try to match any of those.  Then for two-word names, use the first as the first name and the second as the last name.  For longer names, maybe use the first two words as the first name and the rest as the last.

Comment: What if someone has a double barrelled surname though? Also, matching titles to a list can be time consuming.

Comment: Well it's not possible to tell if "Vaughan" in the name "Steven Vaughan Williams" is a middle name or part of the last name, so I don't think you can do better than just guessing.

Comment: Actually, I guess you could have a list of common double barrelled surnames and common two-word first names...

Comment: I thought about storing lists of common names. But am worrying about the performance cost

Comment: I hope you don't have any Asian users. Your simple heuristic will break for them.

Comment: Name can potentially be anyone in the UK

Answer (score 3):

Don't. Don't try to interpret a name in a program. You'll <s>never ever</s> *only sometimes* get it right.

People naming is so extremely complicated that it study, called **anthroponymia**, is the matter of a branch of antropology.

Let's imagine you begin with a title, a given name, a middle name and a family name. Being the family name the name of the father. So you just split the name in components and assign each component.

But, this approach is plain wrong in hundreds of cases. Some people just use one given name and one family name. Others (spanish for example) use one given name and two family names. Some cultures (hungarian, some asian) reverse the order to be the family name first and then the given name (eastern order). Some use as family name the name of the mother (matronyms). Some, the name of the clan, or a historical name of the family, or the birth place. Some (portuguese) usually set the mother family name as the middle name. Some people from countries that use eastern order, reverse the order when addressing western audiences, some other people from the same countries, don't. Combinations are infinite. A complete and terrible nightmare.

So, the only correct way, in my opinion, is to leave a single name entity and let the users choose whatever they want to go there. And don't try to interpret it.

But, there are ocasions were some external regulation may require your software to comply with a given set of separated fields. In that case, and only in that case, your only bet is to pass this directly to the users, allowing them to set the fields at their own preference.

Comment: Yes. This is probably the best advice. +1.

Comment: It has to be done this way I'm afraid. Which is why I'm simply designing something that will come out with a fair bet most of the time. Obviously it would be a lot easier letting the user do it but unfortunately the middle man supplies us only with a fullName.

Comment: I think your statement "You'll never ever get it right." might be a bit too strong.

Comment: @BenH never ever. For example, "Jorge Juan García" can't interpret unambigously. It may be "Jorge Juan" "García" or "Jorge" "Juan García". Both perfectly valid. You will need external information

Comment: Suppose it's "Jorge Juan" "García".  And I interpret it this way.  Then I got it correct, this time.

Comment: Suppose it's "Jorge", you got it wrong, this time. Ambiguity killed you.

Comment: @PA But you said I would NEVER get it right!  I'm just saying that even by guessing, I will SOMETIMES get it right.

Comment: You'll only sometimes get it right when it breaks with normal British convention. About 75% of them don't though. So most of the time it'll be right.